# How to animate centered square to the top

Tags: ios, swift, animation, autolayout, constraints

I have a `UIView` in a portrait-only app.

- The view is **centered vertically** and **horizontally** with `AutoLayout` ("manually" using storyboards).
- The `width` equals the `(main)view.width * 0.9`
- The `height` is the same size of the width (it is a square).

I want to tap a button inside this `UIView` and animate it only vertically until it reaches the top border of the screen (eg. height*0.9, 10 pts, whatever is possible).

When I click again, I want to reposition back the view to its original position (centered as it was when I first tapped).

During the transition the square should not be tappable.

After reading many posts I could not understand what's the best way to do this (I red mainly developers saying old techniques using `centerX` should be avoided and lamentations about some versions of the SO behaving in strange ways).

I suppose I should find a way to get the current "position" of the constraints and to assign a constraint the "final" position, but I was not able to do it.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What are the constraints on the view?

Comment: As I said it is centered vertically and horizontally to the ViewController main view, and its height and width are defined as 0.9 of the width of the main ViewController width

Comment: Set uiview center like x=  (main)view.center.x, and y like y= squreView.frame.origion.x+squreView.frame.height/2
All this stuff inside uiview.Animation function

and when your want back set squre center like (main)view.center

Comment: @singh.jitendra this exactly what they say to avoid with autolayout

Comment: than you have one more option
fix size of squre view and change constraints to top bottom left right 
and than make IBoutlate of top constraint
in animation block set that constraint zer0

Comment: Problem this is exactly the kind of thing I didn't want to do (no fixed dimensions)

Comment: @singh.jitendra : would a solution (not really a solution, it was just a try) a really bad one? 

`let superH = self.view.bounds.size.height
let subH = self.box.bounds.size.height
self.menuHeight.constant = -superH+(subH*2)`

I could not find a good algorithm, but the general idea was to assign a constant based on the superview and the square height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can use Autolayout to animate - to take the constraint constraining the centerY and set its constant to a value that would move to the top (e.g., `constant = -(UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 2)`), I would recommend using view's `transform` property.

So to move the view to the top you can use:

```
let topMargin = CGFloat(20)
let viewHalfHeight = self.view.bounds.height / 2
let boxHalfHeight = self.box.bounds.height / 2
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
    box.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
         .translatedBy(x: 0, y: -(viewHalfHeight - (boxHalfHeight + topMargin)))
}
```

You are moving `box.center` related to the `view.center` - so if you want to move the box to the top, you have to move its `center` by half a view's height (because the view's `centerY` is exactly `height / 2` far from the view's `top`). That is not enough though, because then only a bottom half of the box is visible (now the `box.centerY == view.top`). Therefore you have to move it back by the `box.bounds.height / 2` (in my code `boxHalfHeight`) - to make the top half visible. And to that `boxHalfHeight` you add `topMargin` so that there is some margin to the top.

Then, to move the `box` back to original position:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
    box.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
}
```

**EDIT**

If you really want to go with autolayout, you have to have a reference to the `centerY` constraint, so for example if it is created this way:

```
let boxCenterYConstraint = self.box.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor)
boxCenterYConstraint.isActive = true
```

Then you can try this:

```
// calculating the translation is the same
let topMargin = CGFloat(20)
let viewHalfHeight = self.view.bounds.height / 2
let boxHalfHeight = self.box.bounds.height / 2
let diff = -(viewHalfHeight - (boxHalfHeight + topMargin))

boxCenterYConstraint.constant = diff
self.view.setNeedsLayout()
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

And animation back:

```
boxCenterYConstraint.constant = 0
self.view.setNeedsLayout()
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Comment: The first code moves the view down (and it's half off-screen). I want it up and 10 pts (or so..., just to avoid collisions with time, battery, etc.) starting from the top. Prepending a minus sign to self.view... causes the same effect (but starting from top)

Comment: `CGAffineTransform.identity.translatedBy(x: 0, y: -(self.view.bounds.height / 2))` does not work? it should move the view to the top (that minus sign was my mistake..)

Comment: It moves the view to the top BUT it's displayed half off-screen: it should be entirely (any device) on screen and there should be 10 pts of margin too

Comment: This one works, but I have only tried i6-simulator: `self.box.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity.translatedBy(x: 0, y: -self.view.bounds.height/2 + self.box.bounds.height/2 + 20)` and I haven't had the time to explain this solution to myself

Comment: well, the thing is that I don't know how far you want to move it.. but it should be pretty self explanatory how to move it up as much as you need (take view bounds, or box bounds and calculate how far you want to move it)

Comment: 20 pts from the top is absolutely fine (I'm in a modal, no safe area strictly required, and this is a login screen). What I don't get is the reason for the double division, but I suppose this can have something related to the fact that the hypotetical registration point of the view is not its top left corner but the center (of course, correct me if I'm wrong, I'm quite good at being wrong  ;-)  )

Comment: you are moving `box`'s center related to the `view`'s center - so if you want to move the `box` to the top, you have to move its center by half a view's height (because the `view`'s center is exactly `height/2` far from the `view`'s top). That is not enough though, because then only a bottom half of the box is visible (now the `box`'s center is at the `view`'s top). Therefore you have to move it back by the `box.bounds.height/2` - to make the top half visible. That means you want to move it by: `y: -(view.bounds.height/2 -(box.bounds.height/2 + 20))`.. additional 20 points are the margin..

Comment: I can use your solution but: do you feel there's no autolayout solution available starting from my original situation? I searched a lot but I could not find anything useful

Comment: I have not tried the last portion but of course it was useful, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are all going the wrong way about this.

Add one constraint that pins the view to the top, and add one constraint that pins the view to `centerY`. It will complain, so pick one and disable it (I think the property in Interface Builder is called `Installed`).

If the initial state is the view in the center, disable the constraint that pins it to the top, and viceversa.

Now write IBOutlets for both constraints in your controller and connect them to those constraints. Make sure the declaration of that variable is not `weak`, otherwise the variable will become nil when the constraint is disabled.

Whenever you want to toggle your animation you can enable one constraint and disable the other.

```
@IBOutlet var topConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet var centerConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

func toggleState(moveToTop: Bool) {
  UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25) {
    self.topConstraint.isActive = moveToTop
    self.centerConstraint.isActive = !moveToTop
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
  }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant. I tried adding and removing constraints but that didn't animate. This works!