# Center UIView vertically without relating it to its superview centerY

Tags: ios, autolayout, interface-builder

I have a `UIView` in a portrait-only app. The view is centered **vertically** and horizontally with AutoLayout ("manually" using storyboards).

From the XCode IDE, is there any way to express the SAME vertical relation using the Top instead of the Superview.centerY? Can I perfectly center my view vertically another way?

This is the current situation:

[image]

Comment: I didn't understood what do you want to do exactly. But you can play with the constant and the multiplier.

Comment: What is your goal here? Why can't you use centerY ?

Comment: @Lame: problem with the constant is that is, say, constant!  :-)   And the multiplier is useless without relating it to some fixed value (eg. the height of the view)

Comment: @MilanNosáľ: good question: if I use centerY I can't animate the view the way I asked in another post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47323379/how-to-animate-centered-square-to-the-top) while, maybe, relating anything to top, I can change the top and have my animation working

Comment: I don't see a reason to change center to top - you will face the same problems.. Rather try to be more clear in the original question.. I will take a look at that

Comment: Please, could you tell me what's not clear in the original question? I can try to improve it

Comment: check my answer there.. If I answered it right, no need to add anything.. If not, we can "chat" there

Comment: @3000 I left an answer in your original question

Comment: @EmilioPelaez: thanks, Emilio, I can read it monday, sorry for being so "unreactive", I'm doing many things at a time   :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to express the SAME vertical relation using the Top instead of the Superview.centerY, change `multiplier` to 0.5

[image]

Comment: I still have not tried but I ask: would this position the uiview vertically in the middle of the screen of any device?

Comment: @3000 UIView.centerY = Screen.centerY? Right?

Comment: Top is generically the top of the screen. I try your solution as soon as possible (don't worry if it should take too long, I've dozens of things to do)   :-)

Comment: I tried, it's ok, but this doesn't solve the animation issue (that's why I asked for the top). Anyway, thanks, it was time for me to learn about the safe area   :-)

Comment: @3000 can you explain the animation more clearly? I think i can solve your issue ;)

Comment: @trungudac: I'm sorry. Your answer is absolutely ok by itself. But I should have mention that my question was related to another one (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47323379/how-to-animate-centered-square-to-the-top). I wanted to know if I can animate a view from the center to the top (and viceversa) using autolayout, when the view starts centered either vertically and horizontally. I thought the only way was to position the view using the top and passing as the constant of a constraint a new value for the top.

Comment: @3000, ok wait a moment. I will give your the answer. For both 2 question ;)

Comment: @trungluc: I still haven't had the chance to try it, but thanks for your time and patience. I can test anything next friday, they assigned me some tons of things to do   :-)

Comment: @3000 I always want to know my answer right or wrong ;). I add an answer with a demo project at the question which you mentioned. Let me know if you can try. Hope my answer can help you ;)

Comment: You're great   :-)